# How to override a JavaScript function from a common file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this js code in common js file.

```
$('body').on('click','.close-modal',function(e) {
        if ($('.modal-container').length > 1) {
            $('.modal-container').last().remove();
            $('.modal-window').last().remove();
        }
        else {
            $('.modal-window, .modal-container').fadeOut(500).queue(function() { $('.modal-window, .modal-container').remove();});
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

I want to overwrite this code with my requirement since its common js file it's not good practice to make any changes in common.js. My overwrite function -

```
$('body').on('click','.close-modal',function(e) {
if(strText.length >0 {
            if ($('.modal-container').length > 1) {
                $('.modal-container').last().remove();
                $('.modal-window').last().remove();
            }
}           
e.preventDefault();
        });
```

Since js file called previous, it's not calling my change ... any option to achieve this.

StrText is my json_enoded string.

Comment: `$('body').unbind('click')` before the overridden function

Answer (score 1):

In your load function unbind the event click on body. Clear handlers [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

```
$(function () {
    $('body').unbind('click')
    $('body').on('click', '.close-modal', function (e) {
        if (strText.length > 0 {
            if ($('.modal-container').length > 1) {
                $('.modal-container').last().remove();
                $('.modal-window').last().remove();
            }
        }
            e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```